# Import custom framework extension in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I'm desperately trying to make an application for Android using Android Studio.

Here is my problem:
I'm using a custom android rom on my Pandaboard, and I created a framework extension (java library) which is included in my rom's system.
That means that I have :
/system/framework/com.stooit.MyLib.jar
/system/etc/permissions/com.stooit.MyLib.xml registering my lib.

However, I just can't find a way to include it Android Studio and compile my application.

I tried to include the generated .jar of my lib into Android Studio, however the content is not recognized (the jar is mainly composed of a classes.dex that contain my lib).

Then, I tried to make a new jar with eclipse of my lib, then include it in Android Studio, mark the library as "provided" and then run my application on my board. However, no luck, it just crashes. It doesn't manage to locate the library.

So that's why I'm asking you: Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

The other way I have (but I'd like not to use it) is to copy/paste by android application into my android sources, make an Android Makefile, import my library and build the app with my rom.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your manifest do you a [`<uses-library>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html) tag? That's the magic part required for the device to know which library to load. For compiling, IDK, sounds good what you do.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I wasn't able to try earlier. It works great. That's exactly what I forgot. Thanks for your help!